# How to avoid repeating pattern strings in syntax files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

In my syntax description file I'm trying to define something like the following

```
syn match arbSAMPLEop   "\<\(TEX\|TEX_SAT\|TXP\|TXP_SAT\|TXB\|TXB_SAT\)\>"
syn match arbTexTarget     "\<\(1D\|2D\|3D\|CUBE\|RECT\)\>" contained
syn region arbSampleInstruction start="\<\(TEX\|TEX_SAT\|TXP\|TXP_SAT\|TXB\|TXB_SAT\)\>" end=";" contains=arbSAMPLEop,arbTexTarget
```

This allows to highlight texture sampling instructions and texture targets only inside the region started by a sampling instruction.

What bothers me is that the region starts by `arbSAMPLEop`, but the string to define `arbSAMPLEop` is copy-pasted as the `start=` pattern. Is there any way I could achieve the same without duplicating the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
syn match arbTexTarget "\<\(1D\|2D\|3D\|CUBE\|RECT\)\>" contained
syn region arbSampleInstruction matchgroup=arbSAMPLEop start="\<\(TEX\|TEX_SAT\|TXP\|TXP_SAT\|TXB\|TXB_SAT\)\>" end=";" contains=arbTexTarget
```

`matchgroup` allows highlighting the delimiting patterns of
a region separately from the body of the region.

`:help syn-matchgroup`

If you really had to, you could store a pattern in a string variable, and then use `execute` to build up your `syntax` command. However I doubt this is necessary in a well-structured syntax file.